# RDS Gateway - how to allow a whole subnet or range of IPs for use?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, remote-desktop-gateway

I've setup an RDS Gateway to allow and control RDP access out of the company and it works.  My issues is within the RAP Properties > Network Resources tab, where you add the allowed destination IP, I can only add IPs individually and not subnets.

How can I add a range or subnet e.g. x.x.x.10-x.x.x.x20 or x.x.x.x/24 to this allowed list in the RDS Gateway?

[RAP Properties > Network Resources tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRg9b.jpg)

The above formats aren't accepted.  As a work around previously I've exported and modified the tsgateway.xml export, however I need to add several large subnets now and it's really a viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks